# Vuex access this.$store from getters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm trying to access this.$store.commit from getters section and I see error property '$store' of undefined, I was able to access this.$store from mutations so why not from getters?

my store.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import order from './modules/order/order'
import dialogList from './modules/dialog/dialogList'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: { },
    getters: {

    },
    modules: {
        order,
        dialogList
    }
});
```

my order.js file calling mutation from dialogList

```
const state = {
    order: {
       ...
    }
}

const getters = {
    showInfoDialogWithCalculatedData(state) {
    //... some actions

    //here this.$store is undefined
    this.$store.commit('showInfoDialog', { message: 'test', type: 'error'});
    
    return someData;
    }
}

const mutations = {
    showInfoDialogWithCalculatedData(state) {
    //... some actions

    //here this.$store is defined
    this.$store.commit('showInfoDialog', { message: 'test', type: 'error'});
   
    }
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
}
```

Why this.$store is undefined in getters?

Answer (score 2):

Because getters **should not** commit mutation maybe you can setup a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) so when the getters call an update you can commit or if you **REALY** want to do it you can import the store and call the commit from the store imported.

```
import store from "../index";

const getters = {
  showInfoDialogWithCalculatedData(state) {
  //... some actions

  //Store imported
  store .commit('showInfoDialog', { message: 'test', type: 'error'});

  return someData;
}
```

Comment: mathieu Your answer 'Because getters should not commit mutation' shows that I stuck during refactoring :D thank You so much!